# PyQt Keypress signal to multiple slots in different classes

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a custom table class, where I want to tie the Return key to advancing the edit focus to the next row, as follows:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class App(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # self.shortcut = QShortcut(QKeySequence('Return'), self)
        # self.shortcut.activated.connect(self.plotter)

        table = Table(1, 1)
        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(table)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.show()

    def plotter(self):
        print('I am plotting')

class Table(QTableWidget):

    def __init__(self, rows, cols):
        super().__init__(1, 1)

        self.shortcut = QShortcut(QKeySequence('Return'), self)
        self.shortcut.activated.connect(self.advance)

    def advance(self):
        print('I am advancing')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = App()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Which works fine. But I also want to tie that Return key to a plotting routine in the application in which the table resides. The net effect of this would be hitting the Return key to accept the table edit and advance the table cell focus, then updating the plot determined by those table values.

Implementing the above code in the same fashion for the plotting routine in the main application class also works well. But I can't implement them both at the same time. When I tie the Return key to two separate slots in two separate classes, nothing happens when I hit Return. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: provide  a              [mre]

Comment: Updated with simple example.

Comment: @somethingvague have you tried to connect to the [`cellChanged`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#cellChanged) signal of the table widget (possibly *after* filling it)? I know it's not exactly the same, but it might be what you're looking for.

Comment: @musicamante, yeah, the issue I had was that the plotting routine is part of the main app class, and the cellChanged signal could only connect to methods in the table class. But I'm new to PyQt, so my understanding may not be correct.

Comment: @somethingvague it might be helpful if you include your efforts with that approach.

Answer (score 0):

The activated signal does not trigger since the sequence is ambiguous as the docs points out, so you should use the [`activatedAmbiguously`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qshortcut.html#activatedAmbiguously)  signal

> #### void QShortcut::activatedAmbiguously()
>
> When a key sequence is
>   being typed at the keyboard, **it is said to be ambiguous as long as it
>   matches the start of more than one shortcut.**
>
> When a shortcut's key sequence is completed, activatedAmbiguously() is
>   emitted if the key sequence is still ambiguous (i.e., it is the start
>   of one or more other shortcuts). The activated() signal is not emitted
>   in this case.
>
> See also activated().

<sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>

But unfortunately it will not work since it shoots one at a time, that is to say first the shortcut of the parent(QWidget) and then the shortcut of the children(QTableWidget), who does not meet your requirement.

So in this case a possible solution is to connect the same signal to several slots:

```
class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        table = Table(1, 1)
        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(table)

        self.show()

        self.shortcut = QShortcut(QKeySequence("Return"), self)
        self.shortcut.activated.connect(self.plotter)
        self.shortcut.activated.connect(table.advance)

    def plotter(self):
        print("I am plotting")


class Table(QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, rows, cols):
        super().__init__(1, 1)

    def advance(self):
        print("I am advancing")
```

Another alternative is to use an eventFilter instead of the QShortcut, since the eventfilter will not consume the event as the QShorcut so all the filters will be notified although it may be inconvenient that the widget does not have the focus and therefore does not receive the event of the keyboard:

```
class ReturnListener(QObject):
    pressed = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, widget):
        super().__init__(widget)
        self._widget = widget
        self.widget.installEventFilter(self)

    @property
    def widget(self):
        return self._widget

    def eventFilter(self, o, e):
        if self.widget is o and e.type() == QEvent.KeyPress:
            if e.key() == Qt.Key_Return:
                self.pressed.emit()
        return super().eventFilter(o, e)


class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        table = Table(1, 1)
        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(table)

        listener = ReturnListener(self)
        listener.pressed.connect(self.plotter)

        self.show()

    def plotter(self):
        print("I am plotting")


class Table(QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, rows, cols):
        super().__init__(1, 1)

        listener = ReturnListener(self)
        listener.pressed.connect(self.advance)

    def advance(self):
        print("I am advancing")
```

In conclusion, the best solution is to only have a QShorcut connecting all the slots to the same signal.